# Solve the following equation: $\sqrt{x^2+x}-\sqrt{x^2-x}=x+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I have tried many ways but not success

$\sqrt{x^2+x}-\sqrt{x^2-x}=x+1$
$\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x-1})=x+1$

or $\sqrt{x^2+x}-\sqrt{x^2-x}=x+1 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{\dfrac{x}{x+1}}-\dfrac{\sqrt{x(x-1)}}{x+1}=1 \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{x}{x+1}=1+\dfrac{2\sqrt{x(x-1)}}{x+1}+\dfrac{x(x-1)}{(x+1)^2} \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{(x+1)^2+2\sqrt{x(x-1)}(x+1)+x(x-1)-x(x+1)}{(x+1)^2}=0 \Leftrightarrow x^2+1+2\sqrt{x(x-1)}(x+1)=0 $

I need your help!

Comment: You can eliminate the radicals in several ways, but in the end you'll get a quartic with no "nice" roots.

Answer (score 1):

Using your first approach, square both sides:

$$x \left((x+1) - 2\sqrt{x^2-1} + (x-1)\right) = (x+1)^2.$$  Now rearrange and collect like terms to isolate the square root:

$$2x \sqrt{x^2 - 1} = 2x^2 - (x+1)^2 = x^2 - 2x - 1.$$

Next, square again:

$$4x^2 (x^2 - 1) = (x^2 - 2x - 1)^2.$$

The resulting quartic has a rather complicated closed form, but it does exist; the only thing left is to eliminate extraneous roots.

Comment: can you help me eliminate extraneous roots

Comment: Wolfram alpha derives the roots here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3+x%5E4%2B4+x%5E3-6+x%5E2-4+x-1%3D0 (click "exact forms" to see how messy the solutions are)

Answer (score 0):

After squaring, you face the quartic equation
$$3 x^4+4 x^3-6 x^2-4 x-1=0$$

Since $\Delta=-94208$, there are two real roots. Now, forget the nasty formulae and use inspection or graphing; there are two roots "close" to $-2$ and $1.5$. So, use Newton method and obtain the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & -2.00000 \\
 1 & -2.03571 \\
 2 & -2.03396
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1.50000 \\
 1 & 1.32005 \\
 2 & 1.26513 \\
 3 & 1.26015 \\
 4 & 1.26011
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: how to find the delta

Comment: @AnhDucKieran https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#The_general_case.2C_along_Ferrari.27s_lines